# How is eSIM profile cloning prevented?

Tags: network, iot, cellular

How are eSIM profiles tied to a particular device? That is, what prevents a bad actor from digitally copying an eSIM profile (or, why is the eUICC chip required; can't we have a `soft` or `emulated` SIM)?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few parts to this, so I'll break it into the following questions:

### What keeps an eSIM card from being digitally copied within a phone?

The short answer is that the eUICC chip stores the eSIM profile (or at the very least the important cryptographic keys of that profile) on physically separate hardware and doesn't allow the phone to access them, so the eSIM can't be copied.

The eUICC chip can be seen as having similar properties to a TPM: it is required to be a separate hardware + software component that is tamper-resistant, and it stores key information for eSIM cards privately within its confines [1]. Just like traditional SIM cards, eUICC chips have interfaces that allow user equipment to perform encryption/decryption operations on data, but they do not expose key information to the equipment.

Note that tamper-resistant doesn't mean tamper-proof; there's likely physical attacks that can extract keys from a eUICC chip, but they would require specialized equipment and may destroy the chip in the process.

### What keeps an eSIM from being copied during registration?

The eUICC ensures that SIM cards cannot be read digitally once they are loaded into the eUICC. But what about while eSIM cards are being provisioned? Couldn't a process on the mobile phone read the credentials as they're being registered?

It turns out that GSMA has an entire standardized Public Key Infrastructure (PKI) in place to make such an attack infeasable. Each eUICC chip comes loaded with a public/private key pair, with the public key residing in a certificate signed by one of the approved Certificate Issuers. There are two issuers at the time of writing--Verizon and DigiCert [2].

When a mobile carrier provisions an eSIM to a phone, it verifies the certificate supplied by the eUICC against the publicly available Root CI Certificates. If that passes, it encrypts the eSIM profile using the public key from the eUICC certificate and sends it back to the phone. The phone passes it on to the eUICC, which decrypts the eSIM profile and stores it. Since the private key capable of decrypting the eSIM profile resides in the eUICC, and the rest of the phone has no access that key, the eSIM profile is seen as safe from any digital copying during transit.

### Why can't we have a `soft` or `emulated` SIM?

As we can see from the above two examples, the security of the eSIM profile relies on there being a physical component that cannot have its memory read by the rest of the phone. An emulated SIM would have to store both its PKI and eSIM keys somewhere in storage; an attacker with sufficient privileges on the phone could therefore exfiltrate those keys, thereby achieving digital cloning of the eSIM.

If that's a risk one is willing to take, certainly one hypothetically could have an `emulated` SIM. However, GSMA mandates in its standards that eSIM profiles MUST be stored in a separate hardware + software tamper-resistant location, and makes it clear that PKI keys are not to be issued for devices that do not uphold this requirement [1]. So, you're out of luck if you want to try to hack together an emulated eSIM profile manager.

[1] - https://www.gsma.com/esim/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/SGP.21-v2.4.pdf (Section 4.3, eUICC Requirements)

[2] - https://www.gsma.com/esim/gsma-root-ci/